# How can I make an asp.net website which uses entity framework into a shopping cart which can integrate with a payment gateway?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

I am working on this website: http://wolves.phiresky.com/

It is an ASP.NET webpage using entity framework.

1. How can I make this a shopping cart?
2. How can I make this a shopping cart which can integrate with PayFast.co.za Payment Gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that most developers create a shopping cart, including myself, is to create a object, often called cart, and then place that cart object into the visitor's session.  This way the cart is accessible via the session object each page request.  Integrating with a payment gateway is a whole other matter.  To do that you will need to review the api documentation from the payment gateway company and then call the payment api's as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks,

I did use a session and get the api to work. You can see my progress here: wolves.sitego.co.za

Comment: I upvoted but It will only appear once I have a reputation of 15 :).

Comment: @HarryHathorn Thanks! And thank you for letting me know my answer helped solve your problem.  Happy coding. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to get started with a payment gateway is to try out Paypal, they offer test accounts and there is plenty .Net documentation to get you started. So using that you can run a test and see how online payments can be integrated. Also i see your prices are in ZAR, there is a couple of SA based payment gateway companies that you can easily integrate with, just run a google on SA payment gateway companies.